# Does anyone remember a paper or talk: "Some matrices I have known"?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Quite a few years ago I seem to have read a paper or heard a good talk with the title
"Some matrices I have known". Does anyone recall that, or can give a reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for Paul Halmos's talk *[Matrices I have Met](http://www.worldcat.org/title/matrices-i-have-met/oclc/016310374)*?

Comment: When Google search for "matrices I have known" turned up nothing, I guessed you had misremembered the title, and so I tried a variant. I got lucky and hit it on the first try.